# How do I open a JQuery modal dialog that is exactly the width of all the elements within the DIV?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, width, inline, display

I’m using JQuery 1.11 with the accompanying UI.  I would like to create a modal window based on a DIV, however, I would like to avoid specifying a fixed width on the DIV, because the number of elements is going to vary.  However, I would like to keep all the elements on the same plane, provided there is enough horizontal screen real estate (if there’s not, it is fine for them to wrap).  So I have this DIV

```
<div id="loginBox" style="display:none;">
    <div>Login/Sign Up To Save Your Race Results</div>
    <div id="loginLogos">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Google_plus.svg/491px-Google_plus.svg.png" height="75" /></a>
            <a href='#'><img src="https://hilalcenter.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/icon_facebook.png" height="75" /></a>
            <a href='#'><img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/twitter-icon-png-13-1.png" height="75" /></a>
            <a href='#'><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/linkedin-logo_318-52856.png" height="75" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this style

```
#loginBox {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

and here’s the JQuery that creates the modal

```
   var opt = {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
  }
  $("#loginBox").dialog(opt);
  $("#loginBox").dialog("open");
```

but as you will see from this Fiddle — https://jsfiddle.net/fupcjLr4/3/ , if you click on the “Show” link, once the dialog is spawned, one of the elements wraps to the next line even though there is enough space to display all of them and despite the fact I specified “display: inline-block” on everything.  How do I make my modal open at the size of all the elements on the same plane?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
#loginLogos { white-space: nowrap;}
```

to avoid wrapping to a new line.

Comment: I do want things to wrap if there's not enoguh space.  See this Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/fupcjLr4/4/ .  You can't see all the logos when you click on "Show"

Comment: I would then handle the open event of the ui dialog and inside the handler setting the dialog width dependding on its content width, see here to have an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/tL7mzhfg/3/

Comment: When I open that Fiddle the twitter icon is not visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **width** option and **focus** event. Since you don't know the width of the div you want to show before it is displayed, you need to wait until the dialog is in focus to set the width option. You need to set it before as well, (either to **auto** or something else if you want to set a maximum width for example), else it'll default to 300, messing with the inner div width calculation. Something like this seems to work:

```
var opt = {
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 'auto',
    focus: function(e) {
      $(this).dialog('option', 'width', $("#loginBox").width());
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o5r34a4q/3/

EDIT:

jQuery **width** can sometimes return a rounded down value, which in this case would make the container **width** just a little short. To make it more precise you can use **getBoundingClientRect**, which will give you the precise calculated width. Like this:

```
function open_login_dialog() {
  var opt = {
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 'auto',
    focus: function(e) {
      $(this).dialog('option', 'width', $("#loginBox")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);
    }
  }
  $("#loginBox").dialog(opt);
  $("#loginBox").dialog("open");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o5r34a4q/5/

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Something strange -- when I increased the image sizes to reflect what my widths will actually be, the Fiddle breaks -- https://jsfiddle.net/o5r34a4q/4/ .  Notice the LInkedIn logo is going to the next line.  Is there some way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and the height of the #loginBox to the options before assigning it as a dialog:

```
   var opt = {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: $('#loginBox').width(),
        height: $('#loginBox').height(),
  }
  $("#loginBox").dialog(opt);
  $("#loginBox").dialog("open");
```

See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qadoxm

Comment: Your example isn't working, at least not for me on Mac Firefox or Chrome.  The LinkedIn logo is appearing on the next line.  They shoudl all appear on the same line (assuming there is enough horizontal space, which there is)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `.css`

```
#loginLogos img{
  width:23%;
  margin-left:0.7%;
}
```

use `width` and `height` in `%`, then it will change when you change it's `parent`.

or else remove above and add following to your `js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var boxWidth = $("#loginBox").width();
  alert(boxWidth);
  var imgWidth = boxWidth/5;
  alert(imgWidth);
  $("#loginLogos img").css({"width":imgWidth,"height":imgWidth,"margin-left":2});

});
```

Comment: HOw do I make this work by specifyihng width in a fixed pixel size as opposed to a percentage?

Comment: this is not a `fixed size`, it takes the container width and set image width as `23%` from the container width for each `img`

Comment: I want to use fixed pixel widths because when I use percentages it looks terrible.  This is the Fiddle I have with your code -- https://jsfiddle.net/o5r34a4q/11/ .

Comment: I don't know -- but notice how before the dialog kicks in, everything is perfect (I unhid the DIV) -- https://jsfiddle.net/fupcjLr4/13/ , but when you click "Show" then somehow things get screwed up and one of the logos shifts to the next line.  I would like the dialog to open just as things appear before it opens.

Comment: added another one, please try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks but you're making the height of the entire box equal to the height of one of the images, not accounting for the text that is above the image.  As a result, the login box is smaller than the original DIV size -- https://jsfiddle.net/fupcjLr4/14/